# Unable to bind with active directory

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-ldap, spring-data-ldap

I'm new in this domain and trying to bind with active directory using `spring ldap client` in java. I have already googled this and tried every given solution on internet but it didn't work for me. I'm getting following exception:

```
021-08-02T14:14:04,377 DEBUG [AbstractContextSource] -  Got Ldap context on server [********]
2021-08-02T14:14:04,381 ERROR [UserService] -  #### NamingException #### {}
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A71, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839�]; remaining name ‘/’
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:228) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:397) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1840) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.find(LdapTemplate.java:1861) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.findOne(LdapTemplate.java:1869) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.query.AbstractLdapRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractLdapRepositoryQuery.java:70) ~[spring-data-ldap-2.3.9.RELEASE.jar:2.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryQueryMethodInvoker$$Lambda$1419/947388427.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.findUserByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>${data.ldap.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    <version>${ldap.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Following is what I've tried:**

```
@Bean
public LdapContextSource contextSource()
{
   LOGGER.atDebug().log("using given ldap server config: {}", ldapServerConfig);
   LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
   contextSource.setUrl(ldapServerConfig.getUrl());
   contextSource.setBase(ldapServerConfig.getBaseDn());
   contextSource.setUserDn(ldapServerConfig.getUsername());
   contextSource.setPassword(ldapServerConfig.getPassword());
   contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(ldapServerConfig.isReadOnlyConnection());

   //TODO: To add the support of TLS v1.0/v1.2/v1.3
   if (ldapServerConfig.isTlsEnabled())
   {
      ExternalTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy dirContextAuthenticationStrategy = new ExternalTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy();
      contextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(dirContextAuthenticationStrategy);
   }

   return contextSource;
}

@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(ContextSource pooledContextSource, ContextSource contextSource)
{
   LOGGER.atInfo().log("connection pooling enabled: {}", ldapServerConfig.isConnectionPooling());
   return ldapServerConfig.isConnectionPooling() ? new LdapTemplate(pooledContextSource) : new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
}

private ResponseEntity<ILdapResponse> authenticate(String username)
{
  ResponseEntity<ILdapResponse> responseEntity;
  ILdapResponse ldapResponse;
  try
  {
 User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
```

Furthermore I've tried to connect with the `test server` and it's working fine and successfully connected. Following are the test server details

```
ldap.server.url=ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/
ldap.server.baseDn=dc=example,dc=com
ldap.server.username=cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
ldap.server.password=password
```

Also I've tried to connect with the ldap console and got the successful `PROD environment` connection.I don't know what i'm missing in client due to which i'm unable to connect. Please guide me if i'm missing anything. Thanks in advance

```
ldapsearch -d 3 -x -h <url> -p 389 -D <DN/username> -W -b <base dn> cn
```

Comment: The error you are getting implies that the search can't be performed because it didn't successfully log in with ("bind" with) the given username. That basedn you specify limits *all* searches done on that connection to that scope of LDAP, so for any search performed, you must not include that part of the dn in the search itself. I can't recall if the same thing applies to the username you are trying to log in with ("bind" with) on that connection. You might need to remove the "dc=example,dc=com" from the username because that is already scoped by the baseDn setting.